# Style a RadioButtonInput used as a filter on a react-admin list?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using a RadioButtonInput control wrapped in a Filter component used on a List component. It works, but look a bit big:

[image]

I've tried to wrap it in a Box component or changing the style lnline with: style={{padding: 10}} and can't seem to make a difference. I know I'm missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
  return (
    <Filter {...props}>
      <SearchInput source="q" alwaysOn />
      <RadioButtonGroupInput source="active" style={{padding:  alwaysOn label="" choices={[
        { id: 'true', name: 'Active' },
        { id: 'false', name: 'Inactive' },
        { id: ' ', name: 'All' },
      ]} />
    </Filter>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This element initially has: padding=0, marginTop=8, marginBottom=4
You can style elements like this: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html

```
const useFilterStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  search: {
//  border: '1px solid red',
  },
  active: {
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
//  border: '1px solid red',    
  },
}))

const TestFilter = (props) => {
  const classes = useFilterStyles()

  return (
    <Filter {...props}>
      <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn className={classes.search} />

      <RadioButtonGroupInput source="active" alwaysOn className={classes.active} label="" choices={[
        { id: 'true', name: 'Active' },
        { id: 'false', name: 'Inactive' },
        { id: ' ', name: 'All' },
        ]}
      />
    </Filter>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this and I seem to have very little control of the appearance. I'm trying to make the control a bit smaller. If I set fontSize: '.75rem' nothing changes. I've tried fontSize: '8px' or fontSize: 1 and nothing changes. Why is this?

Comment: This component consists of several levels of other components and the parameter is not applied to the component that outputs the label. In general, the Material-UI library does not provide manual font settings: https://material-ui.com/ru/customization/typography/